# Leave request form (same date entry shows zero)

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to create a leave request form on Cognito.
Say the employee is taking 9/8/16 off and proceeds to put in start date as 9/8/16 and end date 9/8/16, the result is `0` from this calculation:

```
=(EndDate-StartDate).Days
```

How do I make the count `1` with the `=(StartDate=EndDate)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Your very very close with the calculation you currently have. You just need to add a day to your calculation so that a start date of 9/8/16 and an end date of 9/8/16 will give you one day, this will work for the rest of your entered dates as well.

A start date of 9/8/2016 and an end date of 9/10/2016 will give you 3 days. You can check out the updated calculation below and a link to a demo template.

```
=(EndDate - StartDate).Days + 1
```

https://www.cognitoforms.com/templates/shared/CognitoFormsTestAccount/LeaveRequestDemo